how to clean specific folder when deploying to that folder with 'az webapp deploy'
I am trying to deploy a zip file to a specific folder within a webapp, but I want to make sure that folder is empty.
this is my command:
az webapp deploy 
   --resource-group $(ResourceGroup) 
   --name $(AppName) 
   --src-path $zip_artifact 
   --type zip 
   --target-path Document_Path
   --clean false

If I use Clean True, it clean entire root of the app (including outside of Document_Path)
Is there another way to clean just a folder?

Clean flag is implemented to clean the root of the app only but not the specific directories. @Vital

So how would you clean specific directory?

Is the CLI only a requirement for you. @Vital

any type of script will work.

i think i have solved this by using Kudu API, i am still trying to see if that will work for me.

As I have already mentioned, Clean flag is implemented to clean the root directory of the web app only but not the specific directories.
Instead of using az webapp deploy you can use curl command to invoke the web app as detailed below.
webapp="apsbjah"
Resourceg="Jahnavi"
User="$apsbjah"
Password="oSxxxxxZkrvHM"
path="site/wwwroot/A"
curl -u $User:$Password -X DELETE "https://$webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/$path"

Output:


Thank you, the only thing i would do here is to append this to the url:  '/?recursive=true'

It's absolutely insane that this isn't made clear in the docs. In actual fact, the docs appear to describe the opposite of the actual behaviour. WTF Microsoft? I quote the official docs:
-Clean Cleans the target directory prior to deploying the file(s). (pwsh)
--clean If true, cleans the target directory prior to deploying the file(s).  (az cli)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/publish-azwebapp?view=azps-12.4.0#-clean
